# Spark streaming from eventhub: how to stop stream once there is no more data?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

What I am trying to do, is to read some data from my event hub, and save it in azure data lake. However, the issue is, that the stream doesn't stop, and the `writeStream` step is not triggered. I am not able to find any setting to identify when the input rate reaches 0 in order to stop the stream then.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a special trigger in Apache Spark often called [Trigger.Once](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) - it will process all available data, and then shutdown the stream.  Just add the `.trigger(once=True)` after `.writeStream` to enable it.

The only problem with it is that in Spark 3.x (DBR >= 7.x), it completely ignore options like `maxFilesPerTrigger`, etc. that are limiting an amount of data pulled for processing - in this case it will try to process all data in one go, and sometimes it may lead to a performance problems.  To workaround that you may do following hack - assign result of `raw_data.writeStream.....start()`, like `query = raw_data.writeStream....` to a variable - and check periodically the value of `query.get('numInputRows')`, and if it's equal to 0 for a some period of time, issue `query.stop()`